# Error message when loading ggplot2 library in RStudio: ffi_standalone_check_number_1.0.7 not found

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I'm having trouble running ggplot2 on my Mac. When I try to create a barplot using ggplot2, I get an error message that says :

```
"Error in .standalone_types_check_dot_call(ffi_standalone_check_number_1.0.7,  : 
  object 'ffi_standalone_check_number_1.0.7' not found"
```

I've already tried updating packages and reinstalling ggplot2, but the issue persists. I even installed the newest version of R Studio. I expected to be able to create a graph without any issues, but I am having trouble with this error message. I'm wondering if anyone has encountered a similar problem and has any suggestions for how to resolve it?

[image]